# Show the content based on unique selection or with different combination of checkboxes (ej. more than 2)

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, toggle

I need to show the corresponding image according to the checkbox controls selection, it works at the moment of selecting a box and showing its respective content, but if I remove the selection from some of them it doesn't work anymore.

```
   $(".checkboxmark").change(function(){    
      var val=''; 
     if($(this).is(':checked')) {

    $.each($('.checkboxmark:checked'), function(i) {
        val += '#' + $(this).attr('id');        
    });

    switch (val) {
        case '#nationals#usa_canada#latinoamerica':
            $(".div5").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#nationals':
            $(".div1").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#usa_canada':
            $(".div2").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#latinoamerica':
            $(".div3").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#nationals#usa_canada':
            $(".div6").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#nationals#latinoamerica':
            $(".div7").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
         case '#usa_canada#latinoamerica':
            $(".div8").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        default:
            $(".div4").fadeIn(400);
            break;
    }
 } 
});
```

Example:

If I check any unique box, or any combination of boxes shows me correctly the result of the individual selection or the according combination, but if I uncheck or remove any selection there stops working and it doesn't show me the supposed active selection, or the default selection when nothing are selected.

I have my working fiddle in this url: https://jsfiddle.net/alonsoct/9koqe4fr/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does that first if in your logic do?  What are the consequences of it, if you uncheck a checkbox?

Comment: I updated my fiddle but there are many switches jeje if there are a best practice or method to do that I want I will appreciate the help.

Comment: So, I got a little bored: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9koqe4fr/24/ this does involve some changes to your structure, though, which is why I never bothered to make it an answer.

Comment: @AlonsoCT You didn't answer my question about the if statement.

Comment: @Taplar in my fiddle I updated the if statement with the uncheck consequences in the "else" https://jsfiddle.net/alonsoct/9koqe4fr/

Comment: @AlonsoCT why do you need the if at all?  If you removed that conditional, if an element is unchecked, your logic is finding all the elements that are selected and building the string for the switch from that.  So if you selected three, and then unselected one, you *want* it to do that.  There's really no need for divergent logic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my script with an else statement
https://jsfiddle.net/alonsoct/9koqe4fr/

```
$(".checkboxmark").change(function(){    
  var val=''; 
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {

    $.each($('.checkboxmark:checked'), function(i) {
        val += '#' + $(this).attr('id');        
    });

    switch (val) {
        case '#nationals#usa_canada#latinoamerica':
            $(".div5").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#nationals':
            $(".div1").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#usa_canada':
            $(".div2").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#latinoamerica':
            $(".div3").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#nationals#usa_canada':
            $(".div6").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        case '#nationals#latinoamerica':
            $(".div7").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
         case '#usa_canada#latinoamerica':
            $(".div8").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
        default:
            $(".div5").fadeIn(400);
            break;
    }
}else{


 $.each($('.checkboxmark').not(':checked'), function(i) {
    val += '#' + $(this).attr('id'); 
     switch (val) {
     case '#nationals#usa_canada#latinoamerica':
            $(".div4").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
      case '#nationals':
            $(".div8").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
      case '#usa_canada':
            $(".div7").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
      case '#latinoamerica':
            $(".div6").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
      case '#nationals#usa_canada':
            $(".div3").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;    
      case '#nationals#latinoamerica':
            $(".div2").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;
      case '#usa_canada#latinoamerica':
            $(".div1").fadeIn(400).siblings('.imgMap').fadeOut(200);
            break;  
       default:
            $(".div4").fadeIn(400);
            break;

     }

   });

  } 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres no point in using many, many divs to do what you are trying to do. Also if you add more option in the future it will be difficult to manage.  I have removed all but one div and defaulted it to being visible.  Additionally,

1. I have changed the jQuery to set `val` equal to the id of all the elements that are check. (If none are checked than it will be empty, which is fine).
2. Next it sets `val` equal to `all_off` if none are checked.
3. Then, it sets `val` equal to `all_on` if all are check by comparing the numbered checked to the total.
4. Finally, it exports val to the `innerHTML` of the div, displaying it to the user.

```js
/*I need to show the corresponding image according to the checkbox controls selection, it works at the moment of selecting a box and showing its respective content, but if I remove the selection from some of them it doesn't work anymore.*/


/*Example
If I check any box, or any combination of boxes shows me correctly the result of the selection or combination, but if I uncheck any of the boxes stops working the switch script*/

/*If I select a unique option and the removal does not show me the default element */


$(".checkboxmark").change(function(){    
    var val=''; 
        
        $.each($('.checkboxmark:checked'), function(i,v) {
        console.log(v.id);
            val += v.id +" "; 
        });
        if($('.checkboxmark:checked').length==0){
        val = "all_off";
        }
        if($('.checkboxmark:checked').length==$('.checkboxmark').length){
        val = "all_on";
        }
        $('.imgMap')[0].innerText = val;
 });
```

```css
div
{
    background:#ddd;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
 
    
    
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="nationals">nationals</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="nationals" class="checkboxmark">
 <br/>
<label for="usa_canada">usa and canada</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="usa_canada" class="checkboxmark">
 <br/>
<label for="latinoamerica">latinoamerica</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="latinoamerica" class="checkboxmark">
</form> 
     
<div class="imgMap"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to hide the others individual siblings, because the function it's on a map to show the different destinies and I need show the different combinations of those. I have an image for every case.
ej. If I select nationals + usa and canada there will show a map with the destinies of this options; If I unselect nationals and then select latinoamerica the image that will show with only the destinies of selected options

Comment: @AlonsoCT I will adjust but the same idea is true.